Bad closing <a> tag earlier on causes last link in post to be not a link anymore
I just came across a puzzling issue while editing somebody's old post to update a broken link.
Always the last link in the post was not clickable, it wasn't even a link, it was simply text.
It turns out the problem was that some earlier HTML link in the post had <a/> instead of </a>. The other links worked (well, the bad one got extended by a few words but that wasn't noticable because there was just an "or" between this one and the next) but the last link now was broken!
This happens regardless of whether the last link uses HTML or Markdown link notation.

Example:
<a href="https://example.com">Good</a>,
<a href="https://example.com">Bad<a/>,
<a href="https://example.com">Good</a>,
<a href="https://example.com">Good</a>,
<a href="https://example.com">Good but not clickable</a>.

This results in the following HTML on the page:
<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Good</a>,
<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Bad,
<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Good</a>,
<a href="https://example.com" rel="nofollow noreferrer">Good</a>,
Good but not clickable.

Which displays as (currently):
Good,
Bad,
Good,
Good,
Good but not clickable.
At the time of writing this, the last link is not rendered as a link.

It's of course a user error, but it should not exhibit this weird behavior. It should perhaps break the originally-bad link but not others, because this can even happen when the bad link is within a quote, copied from somewhere else.

seems sensible to me. Yes, the output is garbage but so is the input. The result is that the good closing tag closes the bad opening tag. The <a/> is self-closed. So, essentially the content is <a> bad <a></a> <a> good </a>

It's strange to me why the invalid markup doesn't just get stripped out; I'd expect the same as you outlined: the broken tag to get stripped, but the final one to be fine!

The <a/> is stripped out leaving us with nested anchor tags (Which is something the spec explicitly mentions as not supported), and one unclosed one. The browser / renderer makes of it what it can. ¯_(ツ)_/¯ I don't really consider this a bug Stack Overflow should solve given the markup provided was invalid from the start.

@Abdul You're absolutely right– Chrome devtools is clearly doing some sort of sneaky cleanup, which is why I thought the tag wasn't getting stripped... if you open the page source directly, you can see that the invalid <a/> closing tag is just gone, as expected. It's in browsers' hands for how that gets interpreted, not much for SE to do.

@zcoop98 Something is still not right though because in the HTML that gets emitted, the last link doesn't exist at all. It's not Chrome doing that, it's like that in the HTML source already (as seen in the edit Ryan M added into my post). I'm not talking about DevTools (which shows an </a> inserted before the next <a>, but that's not what this is about), I'm talking about actual page source.

@CherryDT Gah, you're right, I'm not sure what I was thinking. I mentioned devtools because that's what I checked first to see the markdown, and it shows an added closing tag where there is none in the source, which confused me to begin with. You're absolutely right that that's completely unrelated to the missing final link though.
